# Getting an unknown provider error with a specific module when minifying

Tags: angularjs, module, minify

When I build my code together, I'm getting an error instantiating the main module because it has a dependency on the below module, which is also getting an error instantiating.  As far as I can tell I'm doing everything right to minsafe the module, but am I missing something?

```
angular.module('exceptionOverride').config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$delegate', '$injector',function($delegate,$injector) {
        return function(exception, cause) {
            var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            var loggerService = $injector.get('loggerService');
            $delegate(exception, cause);
            exception.message = $rootScope.currentState + ': ' + exception.message;

            //send the exception off to the logging service
            loggerService.log(exception);
        };
    }]);
});
```

I can add code for other modules if you think it's needed.

Comment: Is `angular.module('exceptionOverride', []);` defined before this config is executed?

Comment: Yup, it's defined in a global module declaration file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to do the config function: (notice the `['$provide', function($provide){ ...`)

```
angular.module('exceptionOverride').config(['$provide', function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$delegate', '$injector',function($delegate,$injector) {
        return function(exception, cause) {
            var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            var loggerService = $injector.get('loggerService');
            $delegate(exception, cause);
            exception.message = $rootScope.currentState + ': ' + exception.message;

            //send the exception off to the logging service
            loggerService.log(exception);
        };
    }]);
}]);
```

Comment: Ugh, it's always something little like that that I overlook

Comment: No worries, glad it was something that was simple! (don't forget to upvote!)